# Browser Proxy Connection Over VPN

Tags: firefox, proxy, vpn

I have a VPN (pptpd) server configured and a client connected. In the same machine of VPN server, I have a proxy server (port 3128)(squid) running with authentication enabled. When I use the proxy in my firefox browser it works fine. However, when I conect my notebook to my VPN server I can't navigate using firefox + proxy. Just to remember Proxy server and VPN server running in same machine (a VPS). I'm using UFW firewall.

Is there some tips in configuration files (pptpd or squid) to get this problem fixed?

Best Regards!

Answer (score 0):

use squid's access.log to make sure: squid doesn't receive requests from your notebook; check the routing availability between internal IP network of VPN server and proxy address, it must be accessible (pingable). you may use port address translation (PAT) as a simple fix.